# CUDA 6.0 does not detect Visual Studio 10.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, cuda, 64-bit

I am running Windows 7 64-bit with Intel CPU, and am trying to install CUDA 6.0. During the install, it gives a warning saying "No supported version of Visual Studio was found," along with a warning that some components of CUDA Toolkit won't work properly.

However, I have Microsoft Visual studio already installed in the directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0".

Is there some reason why the installation is not seeing it? Do I have to edit the "PATH" environment variable? Or is Visual Studio 10.0 not a supported version? According to the CUDA install page, [Visual Studio 10.0 is supported](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/#install-cuda-software).

If more information is needed, feel free to ask for clarification.

EDIT: I think my Visual Studio 10.0 was faulty, so I downloaded Visual Studio 2012 Express and installed it. After running the CUDA installer, it no longer gave the warning about "No supported version...", and began installing. At the end, it stated the following:

```
Installed:
     - Nsight Monitor and HUD Launcher
     - Nsight C++ AMP Target Support for MSVSMON
Not Installed:
     - Nsight for Visual Studio 2012
       Reason: VS2012 was not found
     - Nsight for Visual Studio 2010
       Reason: VS2010 was not found
     - Nsight for Visual Studio 2008
       Reason: VS2008 SP1 was not found
     - Nsight C++ AMP Debugger for VS2012/VS2013
       Reason: VS2012 and VS2013 was not found
```

Seeing as the Nsight and Nsight C++ AMP Debugger were not installed, are they necessary, or useful? According to [this link](https://developer.nvidia.com/install-nsight-visual-studio-edition), the Professional Edition is needed for these to be installed, so presumably Express wasn't sufficient. Am I still good to go?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio 2010, or do you have Visual Studio 2010 Express?

Comment: Hmm, I noticed that the Visual Studio 10.0 directory is only 550MB in size, which seems far too small (I mainly just use it for it's C compiler to be used for Mathematica) so maybe something's wrong. I'm installing Visual Studio Express 2012 at the moment to see if that fixes things.

Comment: Well, you didn't answer my question. It's easy to answer simply by launching the app and using the Help...About menu item.  If your Visual Studio 2010 install is the *Express* version, that is not a supported version for CUDA 6.0, which is indicated on the [page you linked](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements) Visual Studio 2010 Express does not show up anywhere on that page, although VS 2012 Express does.   Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2010 Express are not the same product. One is supported (by CUDA 6), one isn't.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Hmm, now that I think about it, isn't Visual Express 2012 not supported for 64-bit Windows according to that page (on "Native x86_64")?

Comment: That refers to the code generation target.  Visual Studio express versions can only target x86 (ie. 32-bit) applications (not x64 or x86_64, i.e. 64-bit applications) This 32-bit limitation is inherent in the Microsoft Express product family, and is not related to CUDA.  You can load Visual Studio 2012 Express on a 64-bit OS, and create 32 bit apps, including 32-bit CUDA apps.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: I went ahead with Visual Studio 2012, and got a partial install to work (see question edit).

Comment: The Nsight debuggers are not supported in the Express products.  To determine if your install is working correctly, I suggest following the instructions in the [guide you already linked](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements).  That will provide the best answer to your question "Am I good to go?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely reason that the CUDA 6 installer is saying that "No supported version of Visual Studio was found," is because no supported version of Visual Studio was found.

The [supported versions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements) are:

1. Visual Studio 2012
2. Visual Studio 2012 Express
3. Visual Studio 2010
4. Visual Studio 2008

Note that Visual Studio 2010 *Express* is not listed and not officially supported.

So you may have Visual Studio 2010 Express, or you may have some other Microsoft variant product that happens to install some Visual Studio components but is not one of the above officially supported versions of Visual Studio.

All of the above listed VS products can work correctly in either a 32-bit or 64-bit OS.  The *Express* products as configured by Microsoft do not include a (host) 64-bit compiler, and only support building 32-bit apps.  Likewise, those products can only be used to build 32-bit CUDA apps as well.  But those 32-bit CUDA apps can be built and run correctly in either a 32-bit or 64-bit OS/environment.  The express products also do not support the plug-in necessary to enable the [nsight device code debugger and profiling facility](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition).  However code development, execution, profiling (via the standalone visual profiler, [nvvp](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#visual-profiler)), and *host code* debugging is still possible.

In general the install should be performed and validated using the instructions in the [windows getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements).

Comment: With Express 2012, the deviceQuery.exe and bandwidthTest.exe tests both passed, and I was able to run some of the sample files. Thank you for your time!